# How to save string as json in scala spark

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I have the raw of string in logs file . I do many filter and other operation after that . I have reached the following problem as below. I need to convert the string into json format . So that i can save it as a single object.

Suppose i have the following data

```
Val CDataTime = "20191012"
Val LocationId = "12345"
Val SetInstruc = "Comm=Qwe123,Elem=12345,Elem123=Test"
```

I am trying to create a data frame that contains **datetime|location|jsonofinstruction**

The Jsonofstring is the json of third Val; I try to split the string first by comma than by equal to sign and loop through by 2 and create a map of value of one and 2 as value. But json not created . Please help here.

Comment: is the schema of json known?

Comment: No , key and value may different

Comment: Some time may be more key and value but structure is same separated by comma and equal to sign

Comment: You will need to convert string SetInstruc from key-value pair to a JSON string. I don't think converting to a map will automatically convert to a json.

Comment: Yes, It's not converting into json.there is any other method for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject` to convert a map to JSON and then to a string.

```
    val df = spark.createDataset(Seq("Comm=Qwe123,Elem=12345,Elem123=Test")).toDF("col3")

    val dfWithJson = df.map{ row =>
      val insMap = row.getAs[String]("col3").split(",").map{kv =>
        val kvArray = kv.split("=")
        (kvArray(0),kvArray(1))
      }.toMap

      val insJson = JSONObject(insMap).toString()

      (row.getAs[String]("col3"),insJson)

    }.toDF("col3","col4").show()
```

Result -

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                col3|                col4|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|Comm=Qwe123,Elem=...|{"Comm" : "Qwe123...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: The json depends on the map being fed. Feed "com":"test" to the map as key-value pair. Feed "apivalues":{"apk1":"2","apk":"123"} as key = "apivalues", value as another map having key-value as "apk1":"2","apk":"123"

Comment: I use "toMap" on a list of tuple2, it takes 1st element as key and second element as value. For a complex structure you have it mayn't work as is. You need to enhance the mechanism to build the map. However JSONObject will work as shown here for the map.